# Magento 2.3.4 - Swatch Renderer assumes all attributes are swatches

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

[See line 726 of the new swatch-renderer.js file for Magento 2.3.4 here.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/3811867ece26319b090539a7fd7de4352fecf476/app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js#L726)

The `jsonSwatchConfig` JSON object only includes data for swatch-type attributes. (See `\Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data::getSwatchAttributes`.) However, the above line in the latest version of `swatch-renderer.js` assumes that all attributes it encounters `_onClick` will exist in this JSON.

This results in the following error when clicking non-swatch attributes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'additional_data' of undefined
```

It is possible to mix swatch and non-swatch attributes in a Configurable product. Is this a new core bug in 2.3.4?

Comment: I created a bug here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26517

Comment: Did you find any solution I am getting same error after upgrading 2.3.2 to 2.3.4

Comment: do you have found a solution for 2.3.4 version?

Answer (score 0):

My visual (image) switches stopped working since upgrading into 2.3.4.

After going through the files etc, I am very surprised to see no "swatch-renderer.js" file under vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js"...

I already have it overridden since v2.3.2, that worked fine before, also worked on v2.3.3. But for some reason since it's not being referenced from the XML, I can see that my overriding file isn't going to work unless I re-create that reference.

It's very annoying having to change the code to adapt to the new version, it defeats the object of "have your overriding code separately under /app/code & /app/design etc, so that when the system is updated it won't break" after this release however, I am having exactly that problem which sets me back to re-develop this in some (or another!?) way...

Just makes me shout... "Why!?"

[image]